# Error al conectarme desde .net a Oracle

Tags: .net, oracle, oledb

Estoy montando un nuevo servidor WS2012R2 para alojar aplicaciones; las aplicaciones están hechas en .NET 2.0 en adelante y se conectan a Oracle 10g.

Las conexiones se hacen mediante OLEDB.

En el nuevo servidor ya instalé el cliente de Oracle y tnsping y funciona con normalidad, pero al momento de conectarme desde mi app me sale el siguiente error:

> Oracle client and networking components were not found. These
>   components are supplied by Oracle Corporation and are part of the
>   Oracle Version 7.3.3 or later client software installation.
>
> Provider is unable to function until these components are installed.

**¿Cuál puede ser la solución a esta situación?**

---

Ahora que me doy cuenta todo nace así: Esta era una app en .net 1.1 (imagino que por ende en x32), esta fue migrada a vs2008 con .net 2.0, cuando lo compilo para x86 aparece el mensaje de la pregunta (mas arriba), cuando lo compilo para x64 aparece el mensaje: "El proveedor 'MSDAORA.1' no está registrado en el equipo local." todas las pruebas ahora las estoy corriendo sobre un w7x64 y ws2012x64, creo que con esa información adicional ya me podrían ayudar a identificar el problema.

Comment: ¿Que has consultado hasta el momento? Al leer la descripción del error puedo interpretarlo como que te falta algo por instalar. revisa esta [entrada en Oracle](https://community.oracle.com/thread/334936) para intentar la solución que allí proponen. También consulta esta [entrada en MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152516.aspx).

Comment: Bueno esos enlaces que me pasaste ya los revise, y muuuuuchos mas que encontré en la red, y pos no logro encontrar alguna solución es por es oque recurrí a consultar por este medio.

Comment: Comprendo, para ello, te sugiero editar tu pregunta para agregar la información y todo lo que has intentado hasta el momento para que otros usuarios proporcionen respuestas mas acertadas. Por ejemplo: ¿puedes explicar mejor a qué te refieres con `conectarme desde mi app`?

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que tienes que instalar ODAC en la pc desde donde te conectes a Oracle

[64-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html)

no se sobre que version de windows vas a ejecutar, quizas sino es 64bit debas buscar el link con esa distribucion

Con el ODAC tendras las librerias para poder conectarte, contando con el `tnsname.ora`

Despues usa las librerias que ODAC instala para desarrollar, no uses las que incluye el framework de .net porque estas deprecadas

[Build a .NET Application on the Oracle Database with Visual Studio 2005 or 2008](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/cook-vs08-088541.html)

en el articulo veras como definir el conection string

Comment: Que tal Leandro? bueno no se si sea necesario el ODAC ya que la app (aplicación) se conecta con el OLEDB (using System.Data.OleDb;), si estoy trabajando con OLEDB es necesario el ODAC? aparte hay una maquina que no tiene ODAC y si funciona, la maquina donde quiero ejecutar la app es un WS2012R2x64. Saludos.

Comment: el odac lo necesitas igual porque usas el provider de Oracle aunque estes con la libreria de oledb. Ademas no aconsejaria usar las clases de Oledb cuando tienes unas especializadas que oracle provee. Ademas puedes hacer la prueba, create un proyecto winform nuevo y referencia las librerias de Oracle provee con el ODAC, para ver si estas librerias funcionan, asi podrias descartar si es un problema con el proveedor de oledb